# Replace value in mutiple columns based on dictionary map

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks similar to -

```
df = DataFrame(data={'ID': ['a','b','c','d'], 'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[5,6,7,8], 'col3':[9,10,11,12]})
```

I have a dictionary like this

```
mapper = {'a':100,'d':3}
```

Where the key in the dictionary matches the ID in the dataframe, I want to be able to replace the values in say col1 and col3 with the value in the dictionary.
Currently I can do this as such

```
for id, val in mapper.items():
   df.loc[df['ID']==id, 'col1']=val
   df.loc[df['ID']==id, 'col3']=val
```

But I'm wondering if there is a vectorised way to do this outside of a for loop as my dataframe is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to do this.

```
import numpy as np

df["col1"] = np.where(df["ID"].isin(mapper.keys()), df["ID"].map(mapper), df["col1"])
df["col3"] = np.where(df["ID"].isin(mapper.keys()), df["ID"].map(mapper), df["col3"])
```

`np.where` takes condition as first argument, the second argument tells what value to broadcast if `True` and third argument tells what value to broadcast if `False`. If you look at the output of the arguments separately you can understand how it works.

```
df['ID'].isin(mapper.keys())  # argument 1

# returns
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

```
df["ID"].map(mapper)  # argument 2

# returns
0    100.0
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      3.0
Name: ID, dtype: float64
```

```
df["col1"]  # argument 3

# returns
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) :

```
df = df.assign(**{col: df["ID"].map(mapper)
                              .fillna(df[col])
                              .astype(int)
                  for col in ["col1", "col3"]})
```

​Output :

```
print(df)

  ID  col1  col2  col3
0  a   100     5   100
1  b     2     6    10
2  c     3     7    11
3  d     3     8     3
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` the values from dict then `update` in the corresponding cols

```
s = df['ID'].map(mapper)
df['col1'].update(s), df['col2'].update(s)
```

Result

```
  ID  col1  col2  col3
0  a   100   100     9
1  b     2     6    10
2  c     3     7    11
3  d     3     3    12
```